# Need help with Regular Expression to Match Blood Group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that helps me validate a **Blood Group** field - which should accept only A[+-], B[+-], AB[+-] and O[+-].

Here's the regex I came up with (and tested using **[Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/)**):

```
[A|B|AB|O][\+|\-]
```

Now this pattern successfully matches A,B,O[+-] but fails against AB[+-].

Can anyone please suggest a regex that'll serve my purpose?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
(A|B|AB|O)[+-]
```

Using square brackets defines a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which can only be a single character. The parentheses [create a grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) which allows it to do what you want. You also don't need to escape the `+-` in the character class, as they don't have their regexy meaning inside of it.

As you mentioned in the comments, if it is a string you want to match against that has the exact values you are looking for, you might want to do this:

```
^(A|B|AB|O)[+-]$
```

Without the [start of string and end of string anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), things like "helloAB+asdads" would match.

Comment: Leaving the second brackets now also allows "AB|".

Comment: +1 but if the OP wants to use it as a validator you probably should add \A and \z to your regex. The regex becomes \A(A|B|AB|O)[+-]\z

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino: Thanks! Just tested it with http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it seems to validate just fine... I'm going to use it as a custom validator in the jQuery Validation plug-in and all regexes for the validator seem to adhere to the syntax/^regex$/. If I don't use the preceding /^ and following $/, the method fails to validate. So I converted your regex to /^(A|B|AB|O)[+-]$/ - but that doesn't validate my fields either! How to go about this?

Comment: Please disregard my last comment :D That was a silly assumption. Got it working just fine without the ^ and $. Thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 2):

The brackets [] denote a character class, meaning "any of the characters herein".  You want the parentheses () for grouping:

```
(A|B|AB|0)(\+|-)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are building an alternation (e.g. `(A|B|AB|O)`), you should be careful with the ordering of the elements.  Many regex engines will stop at the first alternate that matches (rather than the longest).  If it weren't for the `[-+]` forcing a backtrack, `(A|B|AB|O)[-+]` would not work for `"AB+"`.  It is probably better to say `(AB|A|B|O)[-+]` (but you should check the docs for your regex engine).

Also, if you do not intend to capture the antigen for latter use, you should you use the non-capturing grouping parentheses: `(?:AB|A|B|O)[-+]`.

Furthermore, if you want to ensure that the only thing in the string is a blood type then you need anchors to prevent it from matching only part of the string: `^(?:AB|A|B|O)[-+]$`.  A quick note on anchors,  Depending on your regex engine, `^` may match the beginning of a line rather than the beginning of the string if you pass it a multiline-match option.  Similarly, `$` may match the end of a line rather than the end of a string.  For this reason there are three other anchors in common (but not %100) usage: `\A`, `\Z`, and `\z`.  If your regex engine supports them, `\A` always matches the start of the string, `\Z` matches the end of the string or a newline just before the end of the string, and `\z` matches only the send of the string.

Comment: Thank you Chas. That clarified certain other aspects about this regex :)

Comment: thanks for explaining the non-capturing grouping, I didn't know this

Answer (score 1):

For case insensitive within html pattern attribute you may try this

```
([AaBbOo]|[Aa][Bb])[\+-]


<input type="text" maxlength="3" pattern="([AaBbOo]|[Aa][Bb])[\+-]" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

^(A|B|AB|O)[+-]?$
This will produce the correct out put.