# Validation on blood groups in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my application I going to validate the blood groups, can you tell me how can I validate blood groups.

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you have a list of valid blood groups against which to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for validating a Bloog Group format then check this question. You can use regular expression to validate the format.

[Need help with Regular Expression to Match Blood Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005805/need-help-with-regular-expression-to-match-blood-group)

Comment: ya it is very helpful to me nice reference. Mr.Shoban thank you