# how to validate field to contain only specific values?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

I have an input field to search for a blood type, I want to validate it so the accepted value should be only one of these strings (A+, A-, B+, B-, O+, O-, AB+, AB-), so when the user typed any other string an error message should appear, I used the `identical` option, but it can't compare with more than one field, here is my code:

the `identical` option:

```
identical:{                                             

    field: 'a+',                                               

    message: 'not a valid blood type'                                      

},
```

and here is the `a+` field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="A+" name="a+" />
```

how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: maybe it's easier here to use a dropdown using `<select/>`: [**link**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: @myfunkyside you can't do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a regex setting on the validator.

```
regexp: {
    regexp: /^(A|B|AB|O)[+-]$/,
    message: 'Invalid blood type'
},
```

The regex is taken from this question: [Need help with Regular Expression to Match Blood Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005805/need-help-with-regular-expression-to-match-blood-group)